# Android Service completely stopped

Tags: android, service

I have an android service that I need to stop and restart.  In the service's `onDestroy()`, I have some clean up code that may take a while to execute.

Is there away to notify the application that's using the service that it's finish executing `onDestroy()`? Or something the application can do to check if `onDestroy()` has finish its execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use broadcast in onDestroy() method!

```
Intent intent = new Intent( "Service_destroyed" );
// You can also include some extra data.
intent.putExtra("message", "Service is destroyed!");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

That will notify the other activities. Be sure to register the broadcast first in the activities and unregister when not needed anymore.

Register:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mServiceDestroyedReceiver, new IntentFilter(  "Service_destroyed"  ));
```

Here is the method to catch the broadcast:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mServiceDestroyedReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        Log.d(TAG, "Service is destroyed message: " + message);
      }
};
```

Unregister broadcast receiver:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver( mServiceDestroyedReceiver);
```

Comment: Ok I will check this out.  I'm currently calling unregister with unbind.  I'll try waiting for this broadcast before unregister

Comment: Glad it helps! I am using it in my application to monitor Services from Activities.